# Win 7 user cannot open some .exe-files

Tags: windows-7, permissions

Problem: I tried to start "JDiskReport 1-4" and it did not find javaw.exe so I let it search for the javaw.exe meanwhile I was installing Java 8 RE. It found a javaw.exe and then I pressed "Fix it" which seems not to have gone so well. After Java was installed all icons on shortcuts became Java icons. I then uninstalled Java, then the shortcuts had no icon at all any longer.

[our company or rather IBM who handles our PCs have their own way of updating java which i (a bit thoughtlessly) circumvented by installing directly from oracle]

The symptoms are that *some* .exe-files cannot be run (it seems to depend on where they are located), for the ones that do not run I either get ***File not found*** or ***Access denied***.

E.g. If I use another program that works (totalcmd.exe) and try to start a program say `C:\Windows\cmd.exe` I get ***Access denied***.

E.g. right-clicking on the taskbar to start task manager yields ***File not found*** showing the correct path but somehow still not finding it. Doing "Start/cmd.exe" gives the same error.  Seems all programs under the windows directory gives me ***Access denied*** and any program under Program Files also gives me ***Access denied***.

The user I have is a domain user, if I log onto another PC alls works fine so nothing wrong with the user. Also if another user logs in on my PC he has no problems to start an app so it seems to be linked to my user profile on that particular PC.

In addition on the desktop I don't see any icons for the shortcuts I have there, I guess it is related to the above problem. If I click on a shortcut it asks me what program I would like to use to start it.

I have tried setting file permissions/ownership on `C:\Windows` and `C:\Program Files` but it has not helped and it seems the permissions are ok since they look 
the same if I login on another PC and compare.

I wonder if somebody has had something similar and how it can be solved part from deleting the user account on the PC which would be the last resort. I have spent several hours troubleshooting this so would be grateful for some help.

**EDIT** :

Another thing worth mentioning is that it seems file association works, so for instance clicking on a .pdf file starts adobe acrobat reader or .txt starts notepad++. But when clicking on an .exe doesn't work

Comment: Have you run a `chkdsk` to ensure the drive/file-system isn't corrupted?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes i have, it went through without problem

Comment: There are numerous grammatical mitakes in this question.  For example it took me reading "After ava" three times to understand you mean "java" please go through and fix all mistakes.  It sounds you should open a ticket with your IT support, because we have no idea how they handle Java differently, and how installing java would have changed settings connected to .exe files.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the exact error you see, or copy-paste the full error dialog text?

Comment: @Karan its a bit difficult since I cannot start programs like Outlook and such but I can take a photo, just a sec.

Comment: @Karan so if I start totalcmd and go to the file then try to start it, then it says access denied.

Comment: You describe deleting the user account a last resort.. But making a copy of the user account and creating a new one and copying over anything is so quick to do.  It's so much quicker than reinstalling windows for example. You say you've spent hours troubleshooting. Well, and particularly if other user accounts are ok.. creating a new user seems like something to try and then copying stuff over. Why not try it?

Comment: @barlop can you just copy over the contents of one user account to another? i was think one would have to reinstall applications after deleting the user account, or at least some of it? Yeah well its true about the time spent, i think i will do that then tomorrow. getting late here. thx

Comment: @CyberSpock applications are in c:\program files or c:\program files x86\   so they won't have to be reinstalled. There may be some user specific data  but create a new user account.   I wouldn't try to copy the entire old profile folder over.a new one.  Just copy parts of the older one over. e.g. the contents of desktop folder could be copied into the new one.

Comment: @CyberSpock begin by just creating the new user account, that takes 2 minutes. See if it works. If so, great.. BTW You don't even need to make a backup of the problem profile.. Just copy selected parts over to the new one

Comment: @barlop just a bit uncertain since it is a domain user account so I do not have rights to fiddle with those but i will speak with the IT guys tomorrow, thanks for your help.

Comment: Well I got it finally working, discovered that I could start .exes indirectly by clicking on the extension, so then I got a .reg file and could patch the registry. After that I ran CCleaner which seems to have cleared the registry from errors. Now I am back in business. Thanks all for the help, sometimes just getting some feedback makes you think in other directions.

Answer (score 0):

By cleaning the registry with *CCleaner* and then rebooting I got back online. Seems the install program Java 8 did something wrong in the registry, maybe in combination with our "own" non-standard solution to maintain updates of java.

**EDIT:** No the problem was not fixed with the above instead I had to - as was pointed out in the comments - recreate my profile e.g. login with other user, rename old Users\myuser to Users\myuser.old and then login with myuser. Then copy over the old files.